# AngularJS $templateCache cannot handle url parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been having issues with the browser cacheing my partial templates, so I added a request interceptor that adds a parameter at the end of my urls to try and fix that:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
        request: function(config){
            if(config.url.indexOf('.tpl.html') > -1 || config.url.indexOf('.css') > -1){
                var separator = config.url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
                config.url = config.url + separator + 'lrvc=' + LR_VERSION;
            }

            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

Basically it just adds "lrvc=VERSION" to the end of the url. The only templates I have in $templateCache come from thrid-party modules/directives that have been setup that way. Unfortunately, I'm getting 404 errors when it tries to pull templates from the $templateCache; I'm guessing because the cache tries to pull the exact string, which doesn't match with the url parameter there.

> GET https://my.local.domain/popover/popover.tpl.html?lrvc=2.3.2 404 (Not Found)

Is there a way to get $templateCache to treat this as a normal URL? Or will I have to handle each of these url's differently?

Comment: simple fix...check if that url exists in templateCache first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `if (!$templateCache.get(config.url))` check.

P.S. For real project, sooner or later you will use some build tool to build your js project. And you can use that tool for cache busting. (I.e. grunt-cache-bust in grunt)

Comment: I already use grunt, but had no idea there's a grunt-cache-bust! I'll definitely have to check it out.